# nth-child being ignored by the browser in bootstrap panels

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have `<%= render @inspirations %>`, which renders 4 inspirations:

[image]

**VIEW CODE**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <%= link_to inspiration_path(inspiration) do %>
      <%= inspiration.name %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I want to remove the `border:white` on the left side for odd number and on the right side for even number inspirations (this way the panels touch the edges of the screen).

What I have right now for `nth-child` is being ignored by the browser

**CODE**

```css
.home-panels a:nth-child(odd) .panel-default {
  border-left: 0px !important;
}
.home-panels a:nth-child(even) .panel-default {
  border-right: 0px !important;
}
.home-panels {} .panel-default {
  border: 2.5px white solid;
}
.panel-body {}
```

```html
<div class="home-panels">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="/inspirations/37-testing-to-see-border">
        <div class="white-link">Testing to See Border</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="/inspirations/36-testing-words">
        <div class="white-link">Testing Words</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a href="/inspirations/35">
      <img class="testing-image" alt="This is a Goal-Setter &amp; Bucket List Maker" src="/system/inspirations/images/000/000/035/original/IMG_5106.JPG?1466979374">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a href="/inspirations/34">
      <img class="testing-image" alt="This is a Goal-Setter &amp; Bucket List Maker" src="/system/inspirations/images/000/000/034/original/IMG_5073.JPG?1466810578">
    </a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are applying the `nth-child` to wrong selector, here's your current selector:

```
.home-panels a:nth-child(odd) .panel-default
```

You are saying the `a` would be child of `.home-panels` (which is OK, altought is in fact a grand-child), but parent of `.panel-default`(so not OK), which means this rule would never work given your current HTML markup.

So, instead of the `a` has to be the `div` with class `panel panel-default`, which is the parent of the `a` and which as siblings  `panel panel-default`.

```css
.panel-default:nth-child(odd) {
  border-left: 0px
}
.panel-default:nth-child(even) {
  border-right: 0px 
}
.panel-default {
  background: url("//dummyimage.com/200x200");
  border: 3px red solid;
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2px
}
```

```html
<div class="home-panels">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="/inspirations/37-testing-to-see-border">
        <div class="white-link">Testing to See Border</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <a href="/inspirations/36-testing-words">
        <div class="white-link">Testing Words</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a href="/inspirations/35">
      <img class="testing-image" alt="This is a Goal-Setter &amp; Bucket List Maker" src="/system/inspirations/images/000/000/035/original/IMG_5106.JPG?1466979374">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <a href="/inspirations/34">
      <img class="testing-image" alt="This is a Goal-Setter &amp; Bucket List Maker" src="/system/inspirations/images/000/000/034/original/IMG_5073.JPG?1466810578">
    </a>
  </div>
```